# Defining coloring area in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

[image]

After much work i figured out how to make assymetric sets. Now i am having much trouble defining where the coloring should fill. As you can see in the pic when i fill in the color it fills everything within it. Im trying to figure out how to stop the coloring at the 'closed ball'. if anyone have an idea, i would appreciate it.

my code so far:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick]  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-4,2.5) (-3,3) (-2,2.8) (-0.8,2.5) (-0.5,1.5) (0.5,0) (0,-2)(-1.5,-2.5) (-4,-2) (-3.5,-0.5) (-5,1) (-4,2.5)};
%Open set
\draw [dashed,fill=black!20!green!60!white]  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-3,2.5) (-3.5,2.2) (-4,1.5) (-3,0) (-3,-1) (-2.5,-1.7) (-1.5,-2) (-0.5,-1) (-0.5,0) (-1,1.5) (-2.5,2.5) (-3,2.5)};
%Open ball
\node [dashed] at (-2.1,0.5)[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=12pt] {};
%Closed ball
\node at (-2,0.5)[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=18pt] {};
%Nodes and names
\node at (-2.5,3.5) {$X$};
\node at (-1.8,-1) {$f^{-1}(V)$};
\node at (-2,0.5) {$x_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reorder the closed and open circle and fill the closed one with white.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick]  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-4,2.5) (-3,3) (-2,2.8) (-0.8,2.5) (-0.5,1.5) (0.5,0) (0,-2)(-1.5,-2.5) (-4,-2) (-3.5,-0.5) (-5,1) (-4,2.5)};
%Open set
\draw [dashed,fill=black!20!green!60!white]  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-3,2.5) (-3.5,2.2) (-4,1.5) (-3,0) (-3,-1) (-2.5,-1.7) (-1.5,-2) (-0.5,-1) (-0.5,0) (-1,1.5) (-2.5,2.5) (-3,2.5)};
%Closed ball
\node [fill=white] at (-2,0.5)[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=18pt] {};
%Open ball
\node [dashed] at (-2.1,0.5)[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=12pt] {};
%Nodes and names
\node at (-2.5,3.5) {$X$};
\node at (-1.8,-1) {$f^{-1}(V)$};
\node at (-2,0.5) {$x_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: tikz]

Comment: of course, cant belive i didnt think of that, thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

In case you really require to **not fill** the inner part of a drawing you can use the `even odd rule` key. Unfortunately this makes it a bit more complicated, because you cannot change the `draw` options from `dashed` for the outer border to `solid` for the inner border ...

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{scopes}
    % just to show that the "inner part" of the open set really isn't filled
    % with a color, define a background layer and set it "below" the main
    % layer
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % at the end of the picture fill the background layer with a shading to
    % prove that there is nothing drawn inside of the open set
    execute at end picture={
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \shade [
                shading=radial,
                rounded corners,
            ]
                (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
                (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    },
]
    \draw [thick]
        plot [smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {
            (-4,2.5) (-3,3) (-2,2.8) (-0.8,2.5) (-0.5,1.5) (0.5,0)
            (0,-2)(-1.5,-2.5) (-4,-2) (-3.5,-0.5) (-5,1) (-4,2.5)
        }
    ;
    %Open set
    \fill [
        fill=black!20!green!60!white,
        even odd rule,
    ]
        plot [smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {
            (-3,2.5) (-3.5,2.2) (-4,1.5) (-3,0) (-3,-1) (-2.5,-1.7) (-1.5,-2)
            (-0.5,-1) (-0.5,0) (-1,1.5) (-2.5,2.5) (-3,2.5)
        }
    % don't fill closed ball
        [radius=1] (-2,0.5) circle
    ;
    % draw dashed line for open set
    \draw [
        dashed,
    ]
        plot [smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {
            (-3,2.5) (-3.5,2.2) (-4,1.5) (-3,0) (-3,-1) (-2.5,-1.7) (-1.5,-2)
            (-0.5,-1) (-0.5,0) (-1,1.5) (-2.5,2.5) (-3,2.5)
        }
    ;
    % draw closed ball
    \draw [radius=1] (-2,0.5) circle;

    %Open ball
    \node [dashed] at (-2.1,0.5)[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=12pt] {};
    %Nodes and names
    \node at (-2.5,3.5) {$X$};
    \node at (-1.8,-1) {$f^{-1}(V)$};
    \node at (-2,0.5) {$x_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Seems somewhat complicated to me at this point, since im only just beginning to understand drawing in latex. I will have to mess around with it a bit, to understand how it works. I appreciate the help very much though.

Comment: @Lasse.Jen, [Benjamin's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295970/95441) is perfectly fine and much much simpler if you don't need to keep the inner part "uncolored". But in case you have to, now you need the keyword to look for in the pgf manual ;)

Comment: Its not that i dont need to fill it in, its more that LateX and TikZ is fun to mess around with, and see what beautiful mess you can create. While i do my assignments of course :).